# How to categorize the API into two different swagger documentations? apiModelPropertyAccessExclusions is not working

Tags: rest, api, maven-plugin, swagger-ui, swagger-maven-plugin

We are using swagger-maven-plugin to generate swagger documentation. 
we have the proper annotation for each class and respective method (all API). We are in the need of generating the swagger documentation, and it's generating with all my API's in a single document.

Requirement: Is that possible to generate two set of swagger documents based on the some categorization?Here i am trying to categorize with "public" and "private" 

As per https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md,

I have used *apiModelPropertyAccessExclusions* but it's not working.

> @ApiModelProperty(name="addReport", access="**public**", hidden=true)

pom.xml::

```
<apiModelPropertyAccessExclusions>
    <apiModelPropertyAccessExclusion>public</apiModelPropertyAccessExclusion>
</apiModelPropertyAccessExclusions>
```

Please help me out.